# Pushing Values of an Element to an Array of Object

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I'm trying to push the values of an element into an array of objects but what I'm doing is only returning the first element inner Html for all other elements. The code I'm working with attached. I was actually supposed to get for each element. It works like that for all the contestants. Then I should be able to push to the empty object above to hold all the contestants score out of the fixed value. Like display object = {contestant_one: 5,...}

```js
var total = document.querySelector(".Fixed_number");
var minusBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#minus");
var plusBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#plus");
var GetTotal = document.getElementById('get_all');

var value1 = document.getElementById('Contestant_One');
var value2 = document.getElementById('Contestant_Two');
var value3 = document.getElementById('Contestant_Three');
var value4 = document.getElementById('Contestant_Four');

plusBtn.forEach(function(item) {
    item.onclick = function() {
        if (parseInt(total.innerText) > 0) {
            item.nextElementSibling.innerText = parseInt(item.nextElementSibling.innerText) + 1;
            total.innerText = parseInt(total.innerText) - 1;


            if (parseInt(total.innerText) == 0) {


                const countries = document.querySelectorAll('.country');

                const result = [];

                for (const country of countries) {
                    let resEl = {};

                    [...country.querySelectorAll('span[class^="Contestant-"]')].forEach((span) => resEl[span.className.split('-')[1]] = value1.innerHTML)
                    result.push(resEl);
                }

                console.log(result)


            }
        }
    };
});

minusBtn.forEach(function(item) {
    item.onclick = function() {
        if (parseInt(item.previousElementSibling.innerText) > 0) {
            item.previousElementSibling.innerText = parseInt(item.previousElementSibling.innerText) - 1;
            total.innerText = parseInt(total.innerText) + 1;
        }
    };
});



/*My Console.log(result) output suppose to be something like

0: {one: "3"}
1: {two: "2"}
2: {three: "2"}
3: {four: "6"}
length: 4



but it's only using the first value for other objects so it's returning something like

0: {one: "9"}
1: {two: "9"}
2: {three: "9"}
3: {four: "9"}
length: 4

*/
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="Fixed_number">10</div>
    <ul class="countries">

        <form>
            <label for=""> Contestant_One
        <div id="" class="country">
            <button id="plus"   type="button">+</button>
            <span id="Contestant_One" class="Contestant-one">0</span>
            <button id="minus"  type="button">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
        </form>




        <form>
            <label for=""> Contestant_Two
        <div id="" class="country">
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
            <span id="Contestant_Two" class="Contestant-two">0</span>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
        </form>


        <form>
            <label for="" class="country"> Contestant_Three
        <div id="">
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
            <span id="Contestant_Three" class="Contestant-three">0</span>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
        </form>




        <form>
            <label for="">Contestant_Four
        <div id="" class="country">
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
            <span id="Contestant_Four" class="Contestant-four">0</span>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
        </form>
    </ul>


    <div id="all_total">
        <button id="get_all" type="submit">Get Totals</button>
    </div>






    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[...country.querySelectorAll('span[class^="Contestant-"]')].forEach((span) => resEl[span.className.split('-')[1]] = value1.innerHTML)`

You hardcoded `value1`, it should be dynamic like:

`[...country.querySelectorAll('span[class^="Contestant-"]')].forEach((span) => resEl[span.className.split('-')[1]] = document.getElementById(span.id).innerHTML)`

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in this line of code `[...country.querySelectorAll('span[class^="Contestant-"]')].forEach((span) => resEl[span.className.split('-')[1]] = value1.innerHTML)`

You add `value1.innerHTML` to the result array for every element in the forEach loop.

Comment: That's actually my problem. I don't know how to get all the values. instead of value1.innerHtml @Karlan